# How to store global parameter in IBM Community Server

Tags: eclipse, swt, sametime

I need to store a global parameter in IBM Sametime Community server which can be read by all the users through a sametime plugin.. Which the best way to do it?
The main task is to store a web address from where user can pick other additional config info for the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already you will need the [IBM Sametime Software Development Kit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/toolkits.html).
Look at the stjavatkdevguide.pdf on page 56 it discussed the Storage Service, this is what you will want to use. It explains how to

In a quick simple summary: You will want to create a StoragerServiceListener and add it to the Storage Service using addStorageServiceListerner().  Then to store an attribute, create an STAttribute and assign it your values, then store the attribute with storeAttr().  To Query it use QueryAttr().